# Check URL for a folder

Tags: php

How can I check the URL path for certain folders? I ask so that if we're in a certain folder, we can make a tab selected in the nav bar (just apply a style to that specific li).

So far I know

```
$pagePath = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

So I can get a return that says something like **/music/song/120/** (or whatever it is). What kind of php function can I use that says

if `$pagePath` has "music", then do this. Meaning, if the path is **/music/** or **/music/song**, I should be able to

I plan on using this multiple times,

if `$pagePath` has downloads do this

if `$pathPath` has band do this

and so on.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the path on `/` and then use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check for existence.

However, this could yield problems with paths like `/bands/something/music` where the state would depend on whether you check for `bands` before `music` or *vice versa*. In that case you could `explode()` with `$limit = 2` (to get only two parts, i.e., split on *first* `/` only) and compare your predefined path segments to the first part of the exploded path.

E.g.

```
$path = trim('/bands/something/music', '/');
$parts = explode('/', $path, 2); // ['bands', 'something/music']
switch ($parts[0]) {
    case 'music':
        // ...
    case 'bands':
        // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

e.g.

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'music')>0)
{
# URL contains music
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick way: you could use `strpos`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php